# How to make this series of rules into a mixin?

Tags: css, less

I am using a serie of classes on my CSS like this:

```
.separate-10{
    & > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
}
.separate-20{
    & > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
}
.separate-50{
    & > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    }
}
.separate-70{
    & > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: 70px 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

to use it like this:

```
aside{ .separate-50(); }
```

And I am thinking, that maybe it would be a good idea to make them into a function. Is this possible with LESS? How would you do it?

Comment: You can make it into one mixin that takes the margin top as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mixin like this

```
.separate(@top: 0) {
    & > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: @top 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
aside{ .separate(50px); }

aside{ .separate(20px); }
```

The `@top: 0` defines the default value of `@top` in case you don't pass in anything

You can also take in multiple parameters if needed

```
.separate(@top: 0, @right: 0, @bottom: 0, @left: 0) {
    & > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: @top @right @bottom @left;
    }
}

aside{ .separate(20px, 10px, 3px, 90px); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution of @Huangism will be very flexible.

In the case you will have the classes compiled into your CSS, you could also try:

```
@steps: 10 20 50 70;
.separate-classes(@i:1) when (@i <= length(@steps)) {
@classpostfix: extract(@steps,@i);
@class: ~".separate-@{classpostfix}";
@{class} {
& > * + *{
        display: block;
        margin: @classpostfix 0 0 0;
    }
}
.separate-classes(@i + 1);
}
.separate-classes();

aside{ .separate-50; }
aside{ .separate-70(); }
```